# Will timbre/quality be different if two different people play the same guitar?

Tags: acoustics, instrument

Will [timbre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timbre)/quality be different if two different people play the same guitar? Assume that frequency/pitch and amplitude are same.

Comment: In short: the answer is **yes**, but this [is not really a physics question](http://music.stackexchange.com), is it?

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE. Would like like to defend this as a physics question? Otherwise I will consult the mods at the [musical practice and performance](http://music.stackexchange.com/) beta site to see if they want it moved.

Comment: I'll close it for now, unless and until dmckee hears back from the music site moderators.

Comment: I've had a response from a Music.SE mod who writes *"It seems perfectly on-topic, but I'd be disinclined to migrate it because it's so basic. Yes, different people play differently :P"*. Perhaps the next step would be to spend a little time reading on Music.

Answer (score 0):

The timbre does depend on how one plays the guitar: on the place where one strikes the string and on a few other parameters (http://www.classic-guitar.com/lesson7.html ).